# Using Perl XML::XSLT generates HTML that OUTLOOK has problems with

Tags: html, xml, perl, xslt, outlook

I'm using:

```
my $xslt = XML::XSLT->new( $xslt_file, warnings => 1 );
$xslt->transform( $xml_file );
$$html = $xslt->toString;
```

The result is fine if viewed in a browser- no problems at all. VIEW source shows the HTML is basically one long line, although I see some of what appear to be line breaks here and there (like after the head tag). But there are very few.

If I mail this HTML to outlook, I get psuedo-random problems throughout the HTML document. Like in one place a colour is wrong, in another the wrong font, in another a different issue.

I dug into the outlook source, and discovered that line breaks had been added, perhaps by outlook on some interval. Looks like some forums say every 76 chars.  This is destructive in some cases, particularly when it changed:

```
style="color:#002212;"
```

to

```
style="color:#00221\n2;"
```

To try to fix it I first tried to add

```
<xsl:text>\n</xsl:text>
```

... no difference. I looked up options on `$xslt->toString` to see if I could force it to follow the `\n` in my stylesheet- no.

I finally went back to my Perl and added, as a desperate measure:

```
$$html =~ s|<|\n<|g;
```

and then the Outlook mail was fine- all the issues are cleaned up. I'm not crazy about that kludge because I can't be sure a user might enter a "<" in his text (although I guess it would be converted to its mnemonic). I don't like not having control of line breaks in the stylesheet.

Anyhow this can't be a new issue (although I spent 1/2 the day looking for answers better than mine). I was hoping for something like an option

```
$$html = $xslt->toString(preserveLineBreaks=>1);
```

but I don't see anything like that. There is an xsl option to preserve whitespace, but that's the default which I'm already using. No joy there.

Comment: You can use backticks to add inline code formatting so things that look like HTML tags aren't hidden, e.g. `\`<foo>bar</foo>\`` will generate the output `<foo>bar</foo>`. Also, make sure code blocks are indented four spaces and separated from any previous text by a blank line.

Comment: thanks I did the 4-space trick, but it still killed my tags!

Comment: Then you didn't separate the code from the previous text by a blank line. Note that your second `style="color..."` line isn't highlighted as a code block, either, even though you indented by four spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Things might improve if you pass the resulting HTML through [HTML::Tidy](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Tidy).

Now, the way `XML::XSLT` generates the output is through:

```
sub _my_print_text
{
    my ( $self, $FILE ) = @_;

    if ( UNIVERSAL::isa( $self, "XML::DOM::CDATASection" ) )
    {
        $FILE->print( $self->getData() );
    }
    else
    {
        $FILE->print( XML::DOM::encodeText( $self->getData(), "<&" ) );
    }
}

sub toString
{
    my $self = $_[0];

    local $^W;
    local *XML::DOM::Text::print = \&_my_print_text;

    my $string = $self->result_document()->toString();

    return $string;
}
```

You can write your own version of `_my_print_text`, and, instead of invoking `$xslt->toString`, you can use `$xslt->result_document()->toString()` after setting `XML::DOM::Text::print` to point to your generator.

Comment: Thank-You Sinan , very helpful.